# Netsuite: Is there any way to show all sublist rows of data in one go?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Currently Netsuite will automatically divide the data to pages, 25 rows of data per page. 
Any idea on how to show all data in one page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.getAllSearchResults` or pass `results_per_page` when calling `Application.getPaginatedSearchResults`

`Application.getPaginatedSearchResults({
 ...
 results_per_page: 100
})`